# What is the significance of Parent-Child relationship in self referencing tables in sql?

Tags: sql

I do understand the parent-child relationship of tables using keys but what is its significance in self-reference?

Comment: post a table definition with an example

Comment: update your question and add  a data sample  .

Comment: So lets say we have  a people table. and my ID is 1.  and my Daughter's ID is 2.  but my Daughter has a ParentID of 1 and mine is null.  So in this self referencing example, We know one of the the daughter's parents; and we know my parent has not been defined.  A better Example might be a hierarchy such as a menu structure for a website where a menu item only has one parent. but a child could be a parent to another child.  all Menu_items so no real point for a 2nd table; but with definitions on where they relate in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Self-reference lets you construct table structures for storing hierarchies.

For example, a table of employees that has a self-referencing manager ID lets you store an organizational structure of a company in a single table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    EmployeeId int
,   Name varchar(max)
,   DepartmentId int
,   ...
,   ManagerId int null
)
```